# Show HTTP request status in React

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to build a button to add items to my shopping cart App. When you click the button, it will call an async `POST` request handled by Redux. I will explain my code in the following words:

```
// Home.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import {
    itemsStatusSelector,
    fetchItems,
    itemsSelector,
    addItem,
} from "../redux/itemsSlice";

const Home = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const itemsStatus = useSelector(itemsStatusSelector);
    const items = useSelector(itemsSelector);
    const [itemsNumber, setItemNumber] = useState(0);
    const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false);
    let submitStatus;

    if (itemsStatus === "pending") {
        submitStatus = <span> Loading...</span>;
    } else if (itemsStatus === "fulfilled") {
        submitStatus = <span> Succeeded</span>;
    } else if (itemsStatus === "rejected") {
        submitStatus = <span> Failed</span>;
    }

    // fetch items
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchItems());
    }, [dispatch]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const num = items.length;
        setItemNumber(num);
    }, [items]);

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        setButtonClicked(true);
        dispatch(
            addItem({
                price: 10,
            })
        );
    };

    return (
        <div>
            Price: $10
            <br />
            <button onClick={handleSubmit}>
                Add 
                {buttonClicked ? submitStatus : null}
            </button>
            <br />
            You have
            <span> {itemsNumber} </span>
            items in your cart.
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

Basically, what I am doing in my `Home` component is that every time this page renders, we will first fetch the items (items in the user's shopping cart) from the database, since we only need to fetch once, I put it in an `useEffect` hook. The number of items inside the shopping cart is displayed on the page, I use another `useEffect` hook to update the `itemsNumber`.

If we click the `Add` button, we will fire up a `POST` request. Now, I want to show the status of the `POST` request. The status of the request is indicated by `itemsStatus` in my Redux store. There is three status: `pending`, `fulfilled`, and `rejected`, and the status is the same for different request methods. As you can see, I set the `submitStatus` to different HTML elements in the code, and I put the `submitStatus` in the `button`, so that in the future I can change it to a spinner or an error message to better inform the user.

I want the `submitStatus` to only show up if the user clicks the button, so I add a `buttonClicked` state in the code. Otherwise, the `submitStatus` will show up once the page load since we will fetch the items when the page renders, which will cause the `itemsStatus` to change. The `buttonClicked` will be set to `true` once the users click the button and it will stay `true` after that. Although this can avoid the `submitStatus` to show at the first render, but I don't think this is very neat. Do you have a better way to do it? Only render `submitStatus` when button is clicked.

Here is my Redux thunks:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

export const fetchItems = createAsyncThunk(
    "items/fetch",
    async (_, rejectWithValue) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get("/items");
            return response.data;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            return rejectWithValue(err.message);
        }
    }
);

export const addItem = createAsyncThunk(
    "items/add",
    async (item, rejectWithValue) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post("/items", item);
            return response.data;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            return rejectWithValue(err.message);
        }
    }
);

const itemsSlice = createSlice({
    name: "items",
    initialState: {
        status: null,
        items: [],
        error: null,
    },
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: {
        [fetchItems.pending]: (state, action) => {
            state.status = "pending";
        },
        [fetchItems.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.status = "fulfilled";
            state.items = action.payload;
        },
        [fetchItems.rejected]: (state, action) => {
            state.status = "rejetced";
            state.error = action.payload;
        },
        [addItem.pending]: (state, action) => {
            state.status = "pending";
        },
        [addItem.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.status = "fulfilled";
            state.items.push(action.payload);
        },
        [addItem.rejected]: (state, action) => {
            state.status = "rejected";
            state.error = action.payload;
        },
    },
});

export default itemsSlice.reducer;

export const itemsStatusSelector = (state) => state.items.status;

export const itemsSelector = (state) => state.items.items;
```

I also upload a small demo on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/leyhr). I tried to set up a fake backend by using `json-server`, but I failed... Sorry, I'm not sure how to set it up. The code works on my local machine. At least you can have a better look at my code there. Thank you for your help, I appreciated it!

Comment: Not really an answer to your specific question, but if your goal is to make async requests and be able to show the loading status while retrieving the data, you should at least consider using something like react-query.  Makes this stuff really easy.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer You are right, I just have a look at react-query, it's amazing. I will give it a try. Thank you!